# Meta-analysis with pre-weighted data

Tags: meta-analysis

does anyone know of any references that speak about whether studies can be included in a meta-analysis if the study is already given some kind of weighting factor? For example, large scale survey studies of schools may weight data based on the population. Since meta-analysis includes a weighting factor, I am confused as to how a study that is already given weights can be weighted again. Here is a reference of a study that weights data which I might like to include in a meta-analysis:

O’Donnell, L., Stueve, A., & Wilson-Simmons, R. (2005). Aggressive behaviors in early adolescence and subsequent suicidality among urban youths. Journal of Adolescent Health, 37(6), 517-e15.